# How to format Date in R

Tags: r, date

I have a column with dates with this format:

```
2013-05-25 14:10:00.00
```

...but I want to put it in this format

```
25/05/2013 14:10
```

...so [r](/questions/tagged/r) can read it.

In addition, I want to be able to calculate the time between two columns.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the time column as an object of class `POSIXt` or `POSIXct` just use function `format`, if not convert the column first.

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2013-05-25 14:10:00.00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
y <- format(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
y
#[1] "25/05/2013 14:10"
```

For the difference between two times, you can use `difftime` or more simply the subtraction operator.

```
z <- Sys.time()

difftime(z, x)
#Time difference of 1743.164 days

z - x
#Time difference of 1743.164 days

difftime(z, x, units = "secs")
#Time difference of 150609340 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to convert it before bringing it into r?

Taking your example:

```
> library("lubridate")
> d <- "2013-05-25 14:10:00.00"
> d
[1] "2013-05-25 14:10:00.00"
```

I just put it into a variable as a character type in R.  But, as_datetime() has no problem understanding that format as a date and a time:

```
> as_datetime(d)
[1] "2013-05-25 14:10:00 UTC"
```

If R thinks that the data is a factor when you read it in you might try converting it to a character first.

```
> d <- as.factor("2013-05-25 14:10:00.00")
> d
[1] 2013-05-25 14:10:00.00
Levels: 2013-05-25 14:10:00.00
```

as_datetime in case seems to understand the factor format but it also understand it if converted to a character first.

```
> as_datetime(d)
[1] "2013-05-25 14:10:00 UTC"
> as_datetime(as.character(d))
[1] "2013-05-25 14:10:00 UTC"
```

Comment: My base R didn't come with `as_datetime`

Comment: Sorry, part of the lubridate package.  That would be a tidyverse answer to the question.  

Rui Barradas above answered with the base r solution but lubridate has lots of powerful functions for working with dates so it might be worth a look if you are doing lots of this type of work.

Comment: *Why do you need to convert it before bringing it into r?* This alone deserves an upvote.

Comment: Please add the `library` call to your answer so people know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(yourDate,"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm")
```

---

### More info:

- [TextFunction (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)
- [Format Function (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Comment: That is not an R function @ashleedawg

Comment: @InêsMierPelaez - your question is tagged [tag:excel] and [tag:r], so you will attract excel answers as well as R answers. Remove the excel tag if you don't want excel answers.

Comment: you want it in R?